# Move a file to another directory (folder within a special folder) C#

Tags: c#, file, directory, move

I am trying to move a file but I can only get it working when its to a special folder and not a folder within a special folder.

In case I would like to move it to a folder call "i" located within my documents:

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(MainPath))
        {

            var info = new FileInfo(filename);
            if (info.Length < 1000000)
            {
                File.Move(filename, System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),info.Name));
            }
        }
```

Comment: cw your second parameter (path). Let's see what you're setting the path as

Comment: sorry i dont know what that means, right now the path is to my documents but i want it to my documents/ i. whenever i try fix it i get errors

Comment: @FirebladeDan -- yeah, I agree -- your comment makes no sense.

Comment: What I mean is print out the System.IO.Path... so you can see where it is moving it. it should read C:\documents\filename. I have a feeling its breaking on the combine maybe losing the backslash

Comment: @roryap - type cw then hit tab tab on your keyboard in vs. shortcut chief: cw +tab +tab = Console.Writeline()

Comment: i can never run it to see the path. if i try make a variable as the correct path and use it, it will just give me errors

Comment: What does "special folder" mean? What's special about that folder, or is it just unfortunate phrasing?

Comment: special folder is used to refer to windows folders such as my documents or my pictures without having to write out the whole path which might not work on different os or other peoples computers

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?  If you want to have a folder named "i" beneath the current folder (e.g. your documents), just add it to the call to `Path.Combine()`.

```
File.Move(filename, System.IO.Path.Combine(
    System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "i", info.Name));
```

Comment: tried that, it says "no overload for method ocmbine takes 3 arguments"

Comment: What version of .NET?  If you're using 2.0, you're out of luck.  Anything later than that, it should work.  If you're using 2.0, you should definitely upgrade; it's seriously out of date.

Comment: im using 3.5 only because i want it to run on winxp.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.Combine
(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),info.Name)));
```

What does this show?

Comment: oh now i see what you mean, but when i put that in and run it, the output box doesnt show anything. i also tried a messagebox and the same thing happens. i think its because its in a for loop

Comment: i got it, it shows this C:\Users\William\Documents\IMG_1255.jpg